# Polyline issue for satellite track

Tags: osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid to draw a polyline on an offline map

```
Polyline p = new Polyline(map);
p.setColor(Color.RED);
p.setWidth(1f);
p.setGeodesic(true);
p.setPoints(mypointslist);
```

Here is the problem:
When my points are:

```
1. Lat 45 Lon 170
2. Lat 45 Lon -160
3. Lat 45 Lon -80
4. Lat 45 Lon 0
5. Lat 45 Lon 160
6. Lat 60 Lon 170
7. Lat 60 Lon -160
8. Lat 60 Lon -80
```

The polyline is always a ring...and when I pan around the line it change
The track is not displayed open.
It seems that the start point is always connected with the end point

Someone has an hint that points me in the correct way ?

Thanks all....

Comment: What version of osmdroid

Comment: Current Release: 6.0.1 Feb 18st, 2018